# Need help recreating Menu Nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to replicate the icons with the dropdown in the navigation bar on this website https://www.vannuysmaserati.com/

This is what I have so far. I'm not using icons yet. I would like the dropdowns to use one dropdown menu instead of having a dropdown for each.

I want the Icons to share the same dropdown but change the content depending which icon you're hovered on. or maybe use multiple dropdowns that are positioned in the same place.

Here is a codepen with my code:

https://codepen.io/dmads2355/pen/bQPgbJ

```
<div class="container example2">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/candidbusiness/image/upload/v1455406304/dispute-bills-chicago.png" alt="Dispute Bills">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">P <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <p>phone</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">H <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <p>Hours</p>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
<!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean the dropdowns from call|maps|hours|service? It's not a single dropdown, it just overlaps all dropdowns using absolute positioning.

Comment: @arieljuod Yes, that is what I mean and I also thought that was possibly what was happening. I will look into recreating that. Thanks for your quick answer. Feel free to post more if you want but that is enough information for me to start.

Comment: Just open the inspector and check the styles that are set by bootstrap, you'll need to override some of them (like min-width of the `.dropdown-menu`, or position on some of the elements).